# Acceder a las variables de la actividad desde su fragmento

Tags: android

ACTIVIDAD

Tengo en la actividad con las siguientes variables globales:

```
public String variable="";
public static final String KEYVARIABLE= "KEY";
```

En el `onCreate` modifico el valor de "variable":

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    variable=intent.getStringExtra(KEYVARIABLE);
}
```

En el `onSaveInstanceState` añado al `bundle` los datos que recojo en el `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bd) {

    bd.putString(KEYVARIABLE, variable);

}
```

FRAGMENTO

En el fragmento tengo como globales:

```
public String variable="";
public static final String KEYVARIABLE= "KEY";
```

En el `onCreate`:

```
 variable=savedInstanceState.getString(KEYVARIABLE);
```

Esto no me funciona, ya que me dice que "variable" es vacío. ¿Qué puede estar pasando? ¿Cómo podría acceder a las variables globales de la actividad desde su fragmento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas pasar al `Fragment` variables en el método `onCreate`, te recomiendo que lo crees *programáticamente*.
Lo que tienes que hacer entonces es pasarle las variables al crearlo, guardarlas dentro de un `Bundle` pasarsela como argumento al `Fragment` y recuperarlas cuando las necesites.

Te quedaría algo así:

**Activity**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        variable=intent.getStringExtra(KEYVARIABLE);
        TuFragment fragment = TuFragment.newInstance(variable);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }
```

**Fragment**

```
    public static TuFragment newInstance(String variable) {
        TuFragment fragment = new TuFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(KEYVARIABLE, variable);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle arg = getArguments();
        if (arg != null)
            variable = arg.getString(KEYVARIABLE);
    }
```

El método `onSaveInstanceState` y el argumento `savedInstanceState` del `onCreate` no son para el uso que tu quieres darle, es para guardar y recuperar las variables que necesites cuando el `Activity` o el `Fragment` tienen que reconstruirse.

Un saludo.

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente. Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Excelente aportación!